# how to pass a Struct type into a func and return a list of that Struct

Tags: swift, generics, struct

How would I go about defining a function to take a Struct type and returns an array of them?

Rather than repeat the following function for various types of Structs, I'd like to define one function that can accept a parameter defining the type of Struct to use. I've seen Swift generics docs on simple types and classes but I've had trouble applying this to Structs.

```
func getArray() -> [Thing]? {
    var things = [Thing]()
    let count = … some function …
    if count > 0 {
        for 0..<count {
            let dict = … some other function …
            things.append(Thing(representation:dict))
        }
        return things
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I've oversimplified my code sample. I'll address that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key would be to define a common initializer that the compiler would know is available for all possible struct types. Here's a minimal example:

```
protocol DictionaryInitializable {
    init(representation:[String:Any])
}

func getArray<T:DictionaryInitializable>(ofType type:T.Type)->[T] {
    let dictionary:[String:Any] = ["name" : "Hello World", "amount": 42]
    return [T](repeating: T(representation: dictionary), count: 3)
}

struct Test : DictionaryInitializable {
    let name:String
    init(representation: [String : Any]) {
        self.name = representation["name"] as? String ?? "Default Name"
    }
}

struct AnotherTest : DictionaryInitializable {
    let amount:Int
    init(representation: [String : Any]) {
        amount = representation["amount"] as? Int ?? 0
    }
}

var result = getArray(ofType:Test.self)
print(result) // prints "[Test(name: "Hello World"), Test(name: "Hello World"), Test(name: "Hello World")]"

let anotherResult = getArray(ofType:AnotherTest.self)
print(anotherResult) // prints "[AnotherTest(amount: 42), AnotherTest(amount: 42), AnotherTest(amount: 42)]"
```

Comment: @Carl For classes, you can use the built-in `NSClassFromString()` function to achieve this, but there is no equivalent function for struct types (yet).You would have to create some sort of factory method that can translate string type names into references to types that could be initialized and manually correlate every possible struct type to a string ahead of time.

Comment: your sample code has allowed me to ditch my per-struct functions in favour of a single function. this integrates well with a PINCache extension to allow me to cache Structs. thanks

Comment: @Carl  Glad it helped!!  :)

Comment: I was looking far a way to bundle SwiftUI's `ViewModifiers`, `ButtonStyles` etc together to have a central place for them. Together, they define the skin of an app. You pushed me in the right direction. Thank you.